# looking to see what card would have come

Tags: texas-hold-em

Whilst playing texas holdem, two players are left in a hand - one as the dealer, on the turn the other player bets, and the dealer folds meaning the other player has won the hand - but the dealer out of curiosity then checks what card would have come on the river - is this allowed, and is this considered bad etiquette?

Many thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is called "rabbit hunting," or just "rabbiting." Many casinos and card rooms explicitly prohibit it in their "rules and regulations" document ([example](http://www.thebike.com/poker/rules-instructions)). If you want to try your luck with asking individual dealers to bend the rules... well, do so at your own risk. For home games, there's no single definitive rule about whether rabbiting is allowed or prohibited. You can set the house rule either way. Just make sure everyone knows what it is ahead of time.